# __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_ionic_native__.a.open is not a function

Tags: typescript, ionic3, angular5, google-calendar-api

How can I solve this error:

> WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_ionic_native.a.open is not a function

when I'm using **NishanthKabra/Ionic2_GoogleCalendar** solution.

I want to integrate google calendar in ionic 3 application and create and save events using google calendar, how can I implement that?

My code is:

.ts file:

```
calendarEvent:any = {};

attendees = [{
 email:""
}];

validation:any = {};

CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.settings.readonly"];
APIKEY = "xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
REDIRECTURL = "http://localhost/callback";


sendInvite() {
 if(!this.validate()) {
  alert("Please fill all fields for sending invite.");
  return;
}
this.validation.failure = false;
var startDateTimeISO = this.buildISODate(this.calendarEvent.startDate, 
this.calendarEvent.startTime);
var enddateTimeISO = this.buildISODate(this.calendarEvent.endDate, 
this.calendarEvent.endTime);
this.popLastAttendeeIfEmpty(this.attendees);
// var browserRef = InAppBrowser.open('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=' + this.CLIENT_ID + '&redirect_uri=' + this.REDIRECTURL + '&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar&approval_prompt=force&response_type=token', '_blank', 'location=yes');         
var browserRef = InAppBrowser['open']('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=' + this.CLIENT_ID + '&redirect_uri=' + this.REDIRECTURL + '&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar&approval_prompt=force&response_type=token', '_blank', 'location=no')
browserRef.addEventListener("loadstart", (event) => {
 if ((event["url"]).indexOf("http://localhost/callback") === 0) {
  var url = event["url"];
  var token = url.split('access_token=')[1].split('&token_type')[0];
     browserRef.removeEventListener("exit", (event) => { });
     browserRef.close();

 //Sending the google calendar invite from the google api
 gapi.client.setApiKey(this.APIKEY);
 var request = gapi.client.request({
  'path': '/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?alt=json',
  'method': 'POST',
  'headers': {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
  },
  'body': JSON.stringify({
    "summary": this.calendarEvent.name,
    "location": this.calendarEvent.location,
    "description": this.calendarEvent.description,
    "start": {
      "dateTime": startDateTimeISO,
      "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata"
    },
    "end": {
      "dateTime": enddateTimeISO,
      "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata" // TODO : Parameterize this timezone
    },
    "recurrence": [
      "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1"
    ],
    "attendees": this.attendees,
    "reminders": {
      "useDefault": false,
      "overrides": [
        {
          "method": "email",
          "minutes": 1440
        },
        {
          "method": "popup",
          "minutes": 10
        }
      ]
    }
  }),
  'callback': function (jsonR, rawR) {
    if(jsonR.id){
      alert("Invitation sent successfully");
    } else {
      alert("Failed to sent invite.");
    }
    console.log(jsonR);
   }
  });
 }
});
}

buildISODate(date, time){
 var dateArray = date && date.split('-');
 console.log("dateArray", dateArray);
 var timeArray = time && time.split(':');
 console.log("timeArray", timeArray);
 var normalDate = new Date(parseInt(dateArray[0]), parseInt(dateArray[1])-1, parseInt(dateArray[2]), parseInt(timeArray[0]), parseInt(timeArray[1]), 0, 0);
 console.log("normalDate", normalDate);
 return normalDate.toISOString();
}

addAttendees(){
 if(this.attendees[this.attendees.length - 1].email == '') return;
  var newAttendee = {email:""};
  this.attendees.unshift(newAttendee);
}

removeAttendees(itemIndex){
 this.attendees.splice(itemIndex, 1);
}

popLastAttendeeIfEmpty(itemsList){
 if(!!itemsList.length){
  return itemsList[0]["email"] == "" ? itemsList.shift(itemsList[0]) : 
  itemsList;
 }
 return [];
}

validate() {
 return this.isStringValid(this.calendarEvent.name) && 
 this.isStringValid(this.calendarEvent.name) && 
 this.isStringValid(this.calendarEvent.location) && 
 this.isStringValid(this.calendarEvent.description) &&
 this.isStringValid(this.calendarEvent.startDate) &&
 this.isStringValid(this.calendarEvent.startTime) &&
 this.isStringValid(this.calendarEvent.endDate) &&
 this.isStringValid(this.calendarEvent.endTime) &&
 this.areAttendeesValid(this.attendees);
}

isStringValid(str){
 if (typeof str != 'undefined' && str) {
  return true;
 };
 return false;
}

areAttendeesValid(attendees){
 if(attendees.length == 1 && !this.isStringValid(attendees[0]["email"])){
  return false;
 }
 return true;
}
```

.html file:

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
 <button menuToggle>
  <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
 </button>
 <ion-title>Ionic2 + Google Calendar</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-content padding class="getting-started">
 <ion-list> 
 <ion-item-group>
   <ion-item-divider light>Event Details</ion-item-divider>
     <ion-item>
       <ion-label>Name</ion-label>
       <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="calendarEvent.name"></ion-input>
     </ion-item>
     <ion-item>
       <ion-label>Location</ion-label>
       <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="calendarEvent.location"></ion-input>
     </ion-item>
     <ion-item>
       <ion-label>Description</ion-label>
       <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="calendarEvent.description"></ion-input>
     </ion-item>
     <ion-item>
       <ion-label>Start Date</ion-label>
        <ion-datetime displayFormat="DD MMM YYYY" pickerFormat="DD MMM YYYY" [(ngModel)]="calendarEvent.startDate"></ion-datetime>
     </ion-item>
     <ion-item>
       <ion-label>Start Time</ion-label>
       <ion-datetime displayFormat="hh:mm:a" pickerFormat="hh:mm:a" [(ngModel)]="calendarEvent.startTime"></ion-datetime>
     </ion-item>
     <ion-item>
       <ion-label>End Date</ion-label>
       <ion-datetime displayFormat="DD MMM YYYY" pickerFormat="DD MMM YYYY" [(ngModel)]="calendarEvent.endDate"></ion-datetime>
     </ion-item>
     <ion-item>
       <ion-label>End Time</ion-label>
        <ion-datetime displayFormat="hh:mm:a" pickerFormat="hh:mm:a" [(ngModel)]="calendarEvent.endTime"></ion-datetime>
     </ion-item>
    <ion-item-group>
    <ion-item-divider light>Attendees</ion-item-divider>
     <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let attendee of attendees;let i = index" inset>
            <ion-label>Attendee {{attendees.length - i}}</ion-label>
            <ion-input [(ngModel)]="attendee.email"></ion-input>
            <ion-icon name="md-remove-circle" item-right class="addRemoveBtn" (click)="removeAttendees(i)" *ngIf="attendees.length - i < attendees.length"></ion-icon>
            <ion-icon name="md-add-circle" item-right class="addRemoveBtn" (click)="addAttendees()" *ngIf="attendees.length - i  == attendees.length"></ion-icon>
         </ion-item>
     </ion-list>
   </ion-item-group>

  </ion-item-group>
 </ion-list>
<button primary (click)="sendInvite()">Send Google Calendar Invite</button>

</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, it looks like that error is coming up because you are calling `InAppBrowser.open`. According to the [Ionic Native documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/), it should be `create`, so something more like:

```
var browserRef = InAppBrowser.create(/* URL and arguments */);
```

Note that this is in contrast to the [upstream documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser), which specifies use of `open`.

Additionally, from the Ionic Native documentation, you may need to replace the call to `addEventListener` with `on`, like so:

```
browserRef.on("loadstart").subscribe((event) => {
    /* body of handler */
});
```

Comment: when I change the InAppBrowser.open to InAppBrowser.create, i getting error like this: **property 'create' does not exist on type 'typeof InAppBrowser'**. How can i solve this issue, I need asap solution please help me.
Already i spent too much time, but no luck with any solution.

Comment: Take some time to go through the answer @jess has put forward, you may need to make sure that all your Ionic libraries are installed and line up properly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the required dependencies in your package.json?

Issue may be the changed of ionic packages from **ionic 2.x** to **ionic 3.x**.
Delete your node modules or change your dependencies from your `package.json`.

Try to install the following packages:

```
npm install @ionic-native/core --save

npm install @ionic-native/splash-screen --save

npm install @ionic-native/@ionic-native/status-bar --save
```

Apply this changes to all your imports in `app.module.ts`.

Here some guide on [How to update to Ionic 3.X](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/guide-how-to-update-to-ionic-3-x/87516).